# Why the svg path become strange when I raise the stroke-width?

Tags: html, svg

I try to create a dashboard progress by coding in svg. Here's the code.

```html
<svg
  class="progress-dashboard"
  viewBox="0 0 80 80"
  stroke-width="10"
  stroke-dasharray="127.17, 1000"
  stroke-dashoffset="0"
>
  <style>
/* <![CDATA[ */
.progress-transition {
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.3s ease 0s, stroke-dasharray 0.3s ease 0s, stroke 0.3s ease 0s, stroke-width 0.06s ease 0.3s, opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
}
/* ]]> */
  </style>

  <defs>
<filter id="bloom">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0.5" />
  <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode />
      <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
  </feMerge>
</filter>

<linearGradient id="gradient" x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="50%">
  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#008cfa"></stop>
  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0ffafa"></stop>
</linearGradient>

<mask id="fence">
  <path
    class="progress-dashboard-mask progress-transition"
    d="M 40,40 m 0,-27
      a 27,27 0 1 1 0,54
      a 27,27 0 1 1 0,-54"
    stroke="white"
    stroke-linecap="butt"
    stroke-width="inherit"
    stroke-dasharray="0.73px, 1.3px"
    stroke-dashoffset="0px"
    opacity="1"
    fill-opacity="0"
    filter="url(#bloom)"
  >
  </path>
</mask>
  </defs>

  <g transform-origin="50%" transform="rotate(225)">
<path
  class="progress-dashboard-background progress-transition"
  d="M 40,40 m 0,-27
      a 27,27 0 1 1 0,54
      a 27,27 0 1 1 0,-54"
  stroke="gray"
  stroke-linecap="butt"
  stroke-width="inherit"
  stroke-dasharray="inherit"
  stroke-dashoffset="0px"
  opacity="1"
  fill-opacity="0"
  mask="url(#fence)"
>
</path>

<path
  class="progress-dashboard-frontground progress-transition"
  d="M 40,40 m 0,-27
      a 27,27 0 1 1 0,54
      a 27,27 0 1 1 0,-54"
  stroke="url(#gradient)"
  stroke-linecap="butt"
  stroke-width="inherit"
  stroke-dasharray="inherit"
  stroke-dashoffset="inherit"
  opacity="1"
  fill-opacity="0"
  filter="url(#bloom)"
  mask="url(#fence)"
>
</path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The progress bar is made by three path. All the common arrtibutes is setted at  tag. The stroke-width determins the width of the bar. The fence path is the clip mask to clip the background and frontground path into fence. The problem happened when the stroke-width changed.

[image: This is the result when the path stroke-width equals 10]
It's fine when the stroke-width less than 10.
But when I try to raise the stroke-width, it become strange.

[image: This is the result when the path stroke-width equals 15]
Stroke-width equals 15.

[image: This is the result when the path stroke-width equals 30]
Stroke-width equals 30.

Why the path seems be cut off by a reactangle?

Comment: Are you masking or clipping it? It looks like it's being clipped by a square that's been rotated 45 degrees.

Comment: Looks like you rotated the svg element and he viewBox you are using is too small. Try `svg{overflow: visible;}` to confirm that this is the case. Also you can try a different viewBox like ` viewBox="-20 -20 120 120"`

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks for your answer. But I have tried to add such style, and to change the viewBox. It only changes the position of the path. The path is still clipped.

Comment: @Ouroborus I only added a mask. The shape of mask is also the same path of progressbar. Don't know whitch shape clipped the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate issues. Both the `<filter>` and the `<mask>` element clip the region into which the result of their application is rendered. The default is the object bounding box plus 10% on each side. This is too small for wider stroke widths. You can set `filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` and `maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` to solve this, clipping is now relative to the viewport size.

Unfortunately, this is only good enough for Chrome. Firefox seems to have a bug where, if you apply a filter to the content of a `<mask>`, the filter effect region is always clipped to the bounding box. Changing the `filterUnits` or size properties (`x`, `y`, `width`, `height`) does not have any effect, nor does changing the corresponding properties of the mask.

As a workaround, avoid setting a filter inside the mask. You can achieve (almost) the same effect by first masking the two paths and only filtering (bluring) them later, seperately for each.

```css
.progress-transition {
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.3s ease 0s, stroke-dasharray 0.3s ease 0s, stroke 0.3s ease 0s, stroke-width 0.06s ease 0.3s, opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<svg
  class="progress-dashboard"
  viewBox="0 0 80 80"
  stroke-width="20"
  stroke-dasharray="127.17, 1000"
  stroke-dashoffset="0"
>
  <defs>
  <path id="circular" d="M 40,40 m 0,-27 a 27,27 0 1 1 0,54 a 27,27 0 1 1 0,-54" />

<filter id="bloom" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0.5" />
  <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode />
      <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
  </feMerge>
</filter>

<linearGradient id="gradient" x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="50%">
  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#008cfa"></stop>
  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0ffafa"></stop>
</linearGradient>

<mask id="fence" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <use
    href="#circular"
    class="progress-dashboard-mask progress-transition"
    stroke="white"
    stroke-dasharray="0.73px, 1.3px"
    fill-opacity="0"
  />
</mask>
  </defs>
  <g transform="rotate(225, 40, 40)" filter="url(#bloom)">
    <use
      href="#circular"
      class="progress-dashboard-background progress-transition"
      stroke="gray"
      fill-opacity="0"
      mask="url(#fence)"
    />
  </g>
  <g transform="rotate(225, 40, 40)" filter="url(#bloom)">
    <use
      href="#circular"
      class="progress-dashboard-frontground progress-transition"
      stroke="url(#gradient)"
      fill-opacity="0"
      mask="url(#fence)"
    />
  </g>
</svg>
```